# Access Object Data [name:SteamPLayer:private] in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, steam-condenser

How do I access data in an object array like this? In a foreach loop.

```
[name:SteamPlayer:private] => Pingu Gaige
```

Full array here: http://paste.laravel.com/Xic

I have:

```
foreach($players as $player){
    echo $player.. now I'm lost. 
}
```

Comment: The property is private, this means you can only access it from inside the class `SteamPlayer`. In that case `$this->name` is the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to Steam Condenser's `SteamPlayer` class here. ([Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php/blob/1.3.7/lib/steam/SteamPlayer.php))

```
foreach($players as $key => value){
    echo "{$value->getName()} has a score of {$value->getScore()}\n";
}
```

Comment: All good, I didn't understand those values were pulled form functions rather than straight values.

Answer (score 0):

this could work if not private:

```
foreach($players as $key => value){
    echo 'name : '. $key . ' and ' $value->connectTime . 
}
```